# Node.js: Subpages can't find public statics folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a webapp in Node.js and Express. My subpages (e.g. `/reflection/id`) cannot find my statics folder. Rather than looking for `/stylesheets`, `/javascripts`, etc. (which would be redirected to `/public/stylesheets`, etc.), it is searching within the subpage, i.e. `/reflection/stylesheets`.

You can go to the [Heroku page](http://every6.herokuapp.com/reflection/test) (also linked below) and check out the developer console, and you'll see that it's searching the wrong path.

I suspect that the problem exists in my `app.js` ([link](https://github.com/Gredelston/Every6/blob/master/app.js)), probably around line 24:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Any idea what's going on? Am I not declaring the static path correctly? Any insights are appreciated.

Project on Git: https://github.com/gredelston/every6

Heroku deployment, relevant page: http://every6.herokuapp.com/reflection/test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use absolute URLs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">
```

Otherwise the browser tries to load `stylesheets` relative to the current URL you are viewing.

Comment: Whoops, great catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `app.use(express.static('public'))` , express will automatically find the 'public' folder in your root directory. Here is docs for [express.static](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html)